# how to recover IE8-9 Issue "Web Page Has Expired"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm very frustrated due to IE issue "Web Page Has Expired". It wont come on Chrome or Firefox.I have added asp.net button and the code is like this ;Here is my code

```
 btnBack.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back(); return false;");
```

But when i click on "btnBack" button It gives Error "Webpage has expired".
on IE8,IE9.

Is there any solution for this or any other way to do this.
Every comment will be appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: what is your previous page request GET or POST? Are you adding the event on the same page? Which event you are adding onclick event?

Comment: I am not getting that error @frank

Answer (score 1):

```
btnBack.Attributes["onclick"] = "history.go(-1);return false;";
```

try this ....

Answer (score 0):

n the ASP.NET code, add a function to handle the PreRender event, and have that emit client-side script so that IE will make a GET request to actually display the page.

[Warning: Page has Expired - when users click the back button in Internet Explorer](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Warning-Page-has-Expired-Internet-Explorer.aspx)

[How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067/en-us)